# What is wrong with solution of 'Find that the distance between the circumcenter and the orthocenter of triangle ABC'

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

What is wrong with the solution of 'Find that the distance between the circumcenter and the orthocenter of triangle ABC'.

This is NOT a duplicate of -
[Distance between orthocenter and circumcenter.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334039/distance-between-orthocenter-and-circumcenter)

[image]

As O is circumcenter $ \angle BOD = \angle A$

$\angle OBD = 90$°  - A

$\angle ABL = 90°- A$   ( $ \angle ALB is 90 degrees)

$B = -2A + \pi + \angle OBL$

$\angle OBL = B + 2A - \pi$
 now using sine rule in  triangle OHB

$OH = - sin(\pi - (2A+B) 2R$

$OH = - 2Rsin(2A+B)$

But the answer is R $ \sqrt{1-8\ cosA \ cosB \ cosC} $

maybe my answer is correct but just in the correct form.

Comment: the two is different, let A=90, B=C=45,you will see the difference. your is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"now using sine rule in triangle OHB"

How do you know the circumradius of $OHB$?

In the answer $R \sqrt{1−8 cosA cosB cosC}$ the letter $R$ probably refers to the circumradius of $ABC$.